# Figure x,y of point after forcing angle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, trigonometry, vertices

I have a system of vertices with lines connecting them.  I measure the angle at each vertex by comparing itself and it's "next" point (the vertices are a doubly linked list).

```
var next = this.get("next"),
    dX = next.get("x") - this.get("x"),
    dY = next.get("y") - this.get("y"),
    radians = Math.atan2(dY, dX);
```

When this angle between them hits some threshold, like +/- 2 degrees from a 45 degree...  so like 47 degrees and we want to call it 45...  I need to move this point to the x,y that would be dictated should it have been 45 degrees.  This same thing applies to 135, 90, 180, etc.

I can detect the angle and whether we're within the snap-to-45 zone easy enough, and I know which angle we ought to set it to.  What I don't know how to find is the x,y given that new angle.

```
if(CLOSE_ENOUGH_TO_SNAP) {
    newAngle = Math.round(angle / 45) * 45;

    this.set({
       x: something,
       y: something
    });
}
```

So in the below image, this angle ought to snap to 90 and so I ought to be able to calculate a new x,y given that it's 90, not 92.

[image]

Comment: Ought to be up there now - sorry, forgot to attach.

Comment: may help to specify that if this angle was C on a triangle, i know the points of A and B and the length of the leg AB, but i do not know how long AC and BC will be.

Comment: :( sorry I still cannot see the image :( do I need to follow some link?

Comment: no.  i attached it right to the message.  maybe a cache issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in psuedocode:

```
point dif = currentPt - previousPt

float distance = sqrt(dif.x * dif.x + dif.y * dif.y)

float newCurrentX = previousPt.x + distance * cos(newAngle)

floar newCurrentY = previousPt.y + distance * sin(newAngle)
```

However, if all the new angles are multiples of 45, you could avoid using sin and cos.

For a multiple of 90 degress (or zero degrees),

```
if (newAngle is 90) newCurrentY = previousPt.y + distance 
else if (newAngle is 0) newCurentX = previousPt.x + distance,
 etc.
```

for multiples of 45 degress:

```
else if (newAngle is 135) { 
 shift = distance * CONST_SIN_OF_45; 
 newCurrentX = previousPt.x - shift; 
 newCurrentY = previousPt.y + shift; 
}
```

Comment: Is this possible if I do not know the distance/length of the segment?

Comment: You have the two coordinates, right? If so, then can compute the distance using the pythagorean theorem. That's what the second line with the square root does.